# MVVM is command in model a bad practice?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm wondering, is putting command into model is bad practice in MVVM. For example, I have `ListBox` with `Image` and `Button`. When I click on `Button` I need to open url in browser. So, my code will look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Items">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source={Binding ImageSource} />
                <Button Content="Open url" Command={Binding OpenUrlCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Model:

```
class Model
{
    public string ImageSource {get;set;}

    public string Url {get;set;}

    public ICommand OpenUrlCommand {get;set;}

    public Model()
    {
       OpenUrlCommand = new RelayCommand(openUrl);
    }

    public void openUrl()
    {
        Process.Start(Url); //Open url in browser
    }
}
```

Is it ok, or I should move `OpenUrlCommand` to `MainViewModel` ?

Comment: What is the reason for to do it?

Comment: I'm just wondering where should be OpenUrlCommand in ViewModel or Model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually should implement the *method* in the Model, but the *command* in the ViewModel. This would be much more aligned to the MVVM architecture, and would be no additional work at all for you in this case.

In your ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Model _model;    

    ICommand OpenUrlCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(_model.openUrl); } }

    // ...
}
```

If you want to "send" some URL from the View, you can use `CommandParameter` for that, and have a typed `RelayCommand`.

UPDATE:
Note that, since the DataTemplate where the Command binding resides is the ItemTemplate, you should implement the Command in some `ItemViewModel`, not in the `MainViewModel`. Then, make `Items` an `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>` instead of `ObservableCollection<Model>`, and initialize the collection like this:

```
IEnumerable<Model> models= getSomeModelsToStartWith();
var Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(models.Select(m => new ItemViewModel(m));
```

Comment: @ASh it's expected that every ViewModel has a reference to some Model, usually in the form of a field, injected via constructor or setter. But the main point is: ViewModel contains Command; Command delegates action to the model, be it "the" model, or an item from a list. The `_model` field is only an illustrative example.

Comment: @ASh when you put a Binding inside an `ItemTemplate`, the command automatically binds to the Item itself (usually some sort of `ItemViewModel`). That means it should be implemented in the `ItemViewModel`, actually, not in the `MainViewModel`.